# save output of for loop with zip()

Tags: python

I want to save the ouptut of the loop itration and take it out side as a list

```
a=[7.502210,7.437900,7.373590,7.309280]
b=[58.326596,58.325449,58.324301,58.323153]
for lat, long in zip(a, b):
    tz=tf.timezone_at(lng=long, lat=lat)
    print(tz)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a list comprehension:

```py
lst = [tf.timezone_at(lng=long, lat=lat) for lat, long in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

initialize tf as a list and append the result at each iteration

```
a=[7.502210,7.437900,7.373590,7.309280]
b=[58.326596,58.325449,58.324301,58.323153]
tz = []
for lat, long in zip(a, b):
    tz.append(tf.timezone_at(lng=long, lat=lat))
print(tz)
```

Comment: I'll delete my answer and I up voted yours. Your answer was not visible to me when I posted my answer but I see that they are similar and having both doesn't add value to SO.